# non-generated special member functions vs deleted special member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

This compiles and calls the copy constructor:

```
struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) { cout << "copy ctor!" << endl; }
    //foo(const foo&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    foo a;
    foo b(move(a));
```

This does not compile:

```
struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) { cout << "copy ctor!" << endl; }
    foo(const foo&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    foo a;
    foo b(move(a));
```

I know in the first case why the copy is called - the move ctor is not generated. But why doesn't the second snipper compile? It thought it would call the copy ctor again.

[here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tmRwQwF2568H23Ab) is a link to an online compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference boils down to *absence* of move constructor versus *deleted* move constructor. Those two are not equivalent.

---

In the first case, the presence of your copy constructor prevents the generation of an implicit move constructor. Hence overload resolution on `foo(foo&&)` would find one single viable candidate:

```
foo(const foo& );
```

That candidate is then selected by default.

In the second case, you do have a move constructor. Overload resolution would find two viable candidates:

```
foo(const foo& ); // as before
foo(foo&& );      // now this one also exists
```

The move constructor is the better match, so it's picked as the best viable candidate. However, since it's explicitly defined as deleted, selection of it is ill-formed. Hence the compile error.